# Import nested objects / object functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have,

```
object Foo {
  object Moo {
    fun boo = 4
  }
}
```

And I want to use Moo by importing Foo, in Scala I would do:

```
import Foo._
moo.boo
```

How can I do this in Kotlin?

Comment: There's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6249) in the current compiler that prevents you from importing anything from objects. It should allow importing nested classes and object, but should not allow importing member functions

Comment: This bug has been fixed in October. I've just tried and it works. So the question should be closed now.

Comment: It does work, and all forms of the imports are answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this definition:

```
package a.b.c

object Foo {
    object Moo {
        fun boo() = 4
    }
}
```

You would import and use this as:

```
import a.b.c.Foo

val xyz = Foo.Moo.boo()
```

or as:

```
import a.b.c.Foo.Moo

val xyz = Moo.boo()
```

or finally:

```
import a.b.c.Foo.Moo.boo

val xyz = boo()
```

The last being allowed because they are all object expressions down to the final class holding the method.